# Is there a way to change the size and style of a host window from a navigationpage? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, resize

I have a host window that has a page as follows:

```html
<Window x:Class="myAPP.filesXAML.WinModel"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp.filesXAML"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        Title="myAPP" Height="562" Width="1000">
    <Grid>
        <Frame   NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="/filesXAML/Login.xaml" Background ="White"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then in the code in C# I call another page as follows:

```js
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("filesXAML/UserPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

At this point I want to change the size and style of the host window.

Is there a way to do it?

Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to change the size of MainWindow in Page

```
  public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Application.Current.Windows[0].Width = 100;
            Application.Current.Windows[0].Height = 100;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it allowed me to explore other options and I succeeded as follows:

Application.Current.Windows[0].WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            Application.Current.Windows[0].WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            Application.Current.Windows[0].ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip;
            Application.Current.Windows[0].WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;